# Order array of struct by one chosen attribute in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, comparator

I'm having trouble while ordering an array of a struct that contains 3 `infos` types. I want to order using one of the info, then organize the other 2 infos, but I'm using heapsort and don't know how I would change the code to automatically reorganize. There is any logical hint that would help me? here's the struct

```
typedef struct{
    int orig;
    int dest;
    float cost;
}infos;
```

thanks. i can add any info that help you people help me!

[EDIT]

```
void build ( Armaz x[], int n ){
int i;
float val;
int s;
int f;
for (i = 1; i<n; i++){
    val = x[i].cost;
    s = i;
    f = (s-1)/2;
    while (s>0 && x[f].cost<val){
        x[s].cost = x[f].cost;
        s = f;
        f = (s-1) / 2;
        }
    x[s].cost = val;
    }
}


void heapsort (infos x[], int n){
build(x,n);
int i;
int s;
int f;
float vali ;
for (i = n - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
    vali = x[i].cost;
    x[i].cost = x[0].cost;
    f = 0   ;
    if (i == 1){
        s = -1;
    }
    else s = 1;
    if ( i > 2 && x[2].cost > x[1].cost) s = 2 ;
    while ( s >= 0 && vali < x[s].cost){
        x[f].cost = x[s].cost;
        f = s;
        s = 2 * f + 1;
        if ( s + 1 <= i - 1 && x[s].cost < x[s + 1].cost ) s++;
        if (s > i-1) s = -1;
        }
    x[f].cost = vali;
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing the code would be helpful.

Comment: How do you compare two objects in your heap sort algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you implement your own sorting functions, I recommend you take a closer look at how [the standard `qsort` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) works.

In short: It has an argument that is a pointer to a function used for comparison. That function receives pointers to two "objects" that should be compared, and can do whatever it wants to compare the two "objects". That means one could have three different comparison functions, one for each member of your structure, and pass the appropriate one when needed.

Comment: @JoaoRossetto I didn't say you should use another sorting function, just look at *how it works*, how it does its comparisons. Then I go on to actually tell how the problem can be solved.